# Avoid NVARCHAR when using ToList() in Linq

Tags: sql, performance, linq, linq-to-sql, data-conversion

I have a property in a class with Column(TypeName) set to VARCHAR but when the linq uses ToList(), the SQL generated by linq converts to NVARCHAR instead. Is there a way to avoid nvarchar conversion which happens when ToList() method is called ?

```
var codes = xyz.Where(x => x.IsValid).Select(x => x.Code.ToLower()).ToList();
requests = requests.Where(p => codes.Contains(p.Type.ToLower()));
```

```
Property(c => c.Type).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(3).IsFixedLength();
```

As shown above, though the Type property has column type set to VARCHAR but linq uses NVARCHAR when ToList() is used.

Comment: Maybe this? https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/archive/blogs/diego/workaround-for-performance-with-enumerable-contains-and-non-unicode-columns-against-ef-in-net-4-0

Comment: Thanks a lot @ErikEJ I was able to use varchar by using the PredicateBuilder as described in the document

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own predicate:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
 {
     private static readonly MethodInfo asNonUnicodeMethodInfo = 
                 typeof(EntityFunctions).GetMethod("AsNonUnicode");
     private static readonly MethodInfo stringEqualityMethodInfo = 
                 typeof(string).GetMethod("op_Equality");

     public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> ContainsNonUnicodeString<TEntity>(
                 IEnumerable<string> source, 
                 Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> expression) 
     {
         if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
         if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

         Expression predicate = null;
         foreach (string value in source)
         {
             var fragment = Expression.Equal(
                 expression.Body, 
                 Expression.Call(null, 
                     asNonUnicodeMethodInfo, 
                     Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string))), 
                 false, 
                 stringEqualityMethodInfo);
             if (predicate == null)
             {
                 predicate = fragment;
             }
             else
             {
                 predicate = Expression.OrElse(predicate, fragment);
             }
         }

         return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(predicate,
             ((LambdaExpression)expression).Parameters);
     }
 }
```

See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/archive/blogs/diego/workaround-for-performance-with-enumerable-contains-and-non-unicode-columns-against-ef-in-net-4-0